# Add object to array in nested json object - Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm getting a hard time adding an object to an array inside a JSON object.
This is my state:

```
const DATA = 
{

 data: [

{
  id: 1,
  routeName: 'my 2 route',
  origin: 'Tel Aviv',
  destination: 'Netanya',
  date: '25-01-2021',
  km: '60',
  stops: [
    {
      id: 0,
      address: 'test',
      lat: '32.0853',
      lon: '34.7818',
      customerName: 'test',
      tel: '00000',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      address: 'adddress',
      lat: '32.0853',
      lon: '34.7818',
      customerName: 'test',
      tel: '00000',

    }
  ],
},
{
  id: 2,
  routeName: 'my second route',
  origin: 'Holon',
  destination: 'Hadera',
  date: '12-02-2021',
  km: '70',
  stops: [
    {
      id: 0,
      address: 'address0',
      lat: '32.0853',
      lon: '34.7818',
      customerName: 'customer0',
      tel: '00000000',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      address: 'address1',
      lat: '32.0853',
      lon: '34.7818',
      customerName: 'customer1',
      tel: '00000000',
    },
  ],
},


 ],
}
```

I don't know how to write the reducer, tried few ways but the state doesn't change.
My reducer gets the route id + stop to add this route.
I will be happy for some help here :)

Comment: More detail would be helpful. I am guessing that you are saying you are trying to add another object to the stops array??? Generally your reducer will need to supply a new object with a new array, not mutate the existing one.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to do.
What details could with here?
My biggest problem is that I don't know to how to push this object to this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find the parent route using the route's `id`, and then you'll need to create a new `stops` array by spreading, and adding the new stop.

You can use `Array.findIndex()` to find the actual route, and the slice the array, and update the route. However, another simple option is to map the `data`'s routes, and update the route with the matching `id`.

```
const routeReducer = (state, { type, payload: { routeId, stop } }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'ADD_STOP':
      return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.map(route => route.id === routeId ? {
          ...route,
          stops: [...route.stops, stop]
        } : route)
      }
  }
}
```

Usually in redux it's better to [normalize the state,](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) which makes it easier to update single items.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a reducer that did something like this:

```
const updateItemInArray = (array, itemId, updateItemCallback) => {
    return array.map(item => {

        if (item.id !== itemId) return item;

        // Use the provided callback to create an updated item
        return updateItemCallback(item);
    });
};

const data = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_STOP_SUCCESS':
            return updateItemInArray(state, action.payload.routeId, (item) => ({...item, stops: [...item.stops, action.payload.stop]}))
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

When the action.type 'ADD_STOP_SUCCESS' is called the payload of the action would contain the new stop object you are wanting to add to the state.